# How to get only two column result instead of entire row?

Tags: java, hibernate

My query like this,

```
String sql="select p.productName,p.extendedFlag from product p where productId=? and productVersion=?";
        SqlQuery sqlQuery=session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Product.class);
        sqlQuery.setParameter(0,"newprofin2");
        sqlQuery.setParameter(1,"newprofin2");


        List product =sqlQuery.list();//error at this line
        Product p=(Product)product.get(0);
```

please Help me,
and i am using **Hibernate 3**.

Comment: Please provide stack trace with your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the result as an entity you need to use "select * ..." (so hibernate can map all the column annotations) otherwise you have to stick with selecting only scalar values that are not mapped to the entity and need to be processed on a column basis.

Examples:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm